# Why is the 'tal1' not being added to the next position of the array when set?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to add the 'tal1' form input to a new position in the array every time it is set, so I get a list of self added integers. Dont mind the list, it's just information in swedish.

```
/* <?php
session_start();
?> */

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Mallsida</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$list = array();
$listpos = 0;

if (isset($_POST['tal1'])) {
  $tal1 = $_POST['tal1'];

  if ($_POST['tal1']=='/help') {
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>\'n\' skall antal värden i arrayen skrivas ut.</li>';
    echo '<li>\'m\' skall medelvärdet av talen i arrayen beräknas och skrivas ut.</li>';
    echo '<li>\'s\' skall arrayen sorteras och skrivas ut.</li>';
    echo '<li>\'c\' skall arrayen tömmas helt.</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
  }

  if (is_numeric($tal1)) {
    $list[$listpos] = $tal1;
    $listpos++;
  }

  print_r($list);
  
  /* if ($tal1=='n') {
    echo $lista[0];
  } */

}


?>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="tal1" placeholder="/help"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Skapa triangel">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry if I my question is poorly formatted, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean here. Do you mean that you want to add the value of `$_POST['tal1']` to the `$list`-array on different array indexes? Essentially randomize `$listpos`? Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the php code is fine, but you are not persisting the array so each time you load/submit the page the array gets a new state without remembering the previous numbers.

```
$list = array();
```

So, as you hinted at the top of your code, you could use session to store that array each time, or use other methods, like passing the already added values on the form as hidden inputs, for instance.

At this point, with this part:

```
  if (is_numeric($tal1)) {
    $list[$listpos] = $tal1;
    $listpos++;
  }
  print_r($list);
```

You should see the number submited added to first position of array, only if you submit a number.

**Note**: take care of the initial commented section /* */ as it's outside PHP opening/closing tags and it can be causing you problems.